# Auto-replace within hyperlinks in a Word doc

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, find-and-replace, hyperlink

I have a Word document with a lot of hyperlinks in it. I need to replace the "http:" in all of their addresses with "https:". Is there a way to do that automatically in Word 2013, or am I stuck editing each of them individually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Press Alt+F9. This changes the view to Draft view
2. Press Ctrl+H or Ctrl+L. Word displays the Replace tab
3. In the Find box, enter the portion of the link you want to change
4. In the Replace box, enter the new portion of the link
5. Click Replace All. Word replaces all the text within the exposed links.
6. Close the Find and Replace dialog box.
7. Press Alt+F9 so that field results are showing
8. Select the entire document by pressing Ctrl+A.
9. Press F9. Word updates all the fields in the document, including those links you just changed.

Comment: This is the procedure found at https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010022_Changing_Many_Link_Locations.html

Comment: You beat me to it. Yes. Alt-F9 will toggle showing the actual hyperlink field destinations which can then be edited with Find and Replace.